# Jest test case using queryByText in withrouter(component)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I couldn't able to write test case for withrouter wrapped component. I have writen the test case as

```
it('should render all subpageHeader details', () => {
  const { queryByText } = render(
    <Router history={mockHistory}>
      <SubPageHeader {...defaultProps} />
    </Router>
  );
  const backText = queryByText('Go back to reservation details');
  expect(backText).toBe({});  
})
```

and exported the component as

```
export default withRouter(SubPageHeader);
```

I couldt able toi get the text from the component using `queryByText`. I am getting an error

```
 received value must be an HTMLElement or an SVGElement.
Received has value: null
```

Anyone please give me a solution

Comment: Is the error coming from the `expect` or `queryByText`?

Comment: I'd try to 1) get the `debug` prop from the `render` (`const { queryByText, debug } = render(...)`, then just fire `debug()` somewhere) to se what's actually rendered (it will print the component tree html); then 2) use `MemoryRouter` (from `react-router-dom`) instead of `Router`.